# Linux :search for specific columns with particular string and print on screen

Tags: perl, bash, awk, sed

Its kind of daily record, sample below, though value format will not change but position of field/column of record keep changing which is creating a problem while using `awk,sed,grep`.

Filename.txt - with millions of record

```
abcd D20140624 Useragent username userid 
abcd D20140625 Useragent username1 userid1
D20140626 Useragent username2 userid2
```

result should be:

```
D20140624 username userid
D20140625 username1 userid1
D20140626 username2 userid2
```

IF i use `cat Filename.txt|awk -f ' ' '{print $2,$4,$5}'` - invalid result

Similarly `sed` gives invalid result.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: is `Useragent` constant in all rows?

Comment: Probably best to get whatever creates this `daily record` to output it in a consistent way

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with `awk`

```
awk '!/^D20[0-9][0-9]/ {$1="";sub(/^ /,"")}1'
D20140624 Useragent username userid
D20140625 Useragent username1 userid1
D20140626 Useragent username2 userid2
```

If first field dos not start with a year, remove it and remove extra space.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
awk '{ if(NF==5) print $2,$4,$5; else print $1,$3,$4; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^D[0-9]{8}$/){n=i;break}}
     {print $n,$(NF-1),$NF}' file
```

gives:

```
D20140624 username userid
D20140625 username1 userid1
D20140626 username2 userid2
```

it searches for the the first column that matching `D....` no matter where it is, print it and the last two column.  you didn't specify the rule in detail, so I came with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed command

```
sed -r 's/.*(D[0-9]+) \w+ (.*)/\1 \2/g' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -r 's/^.*(D\S*).*(usern\S*).*(useri\S*).*/\1 \2 \3/g' file
D20140624 username userid
D20140625 username1 userid1
D20140626 username2 userid2
```

Answer (score 0):

`-f` is the argument to tell awk to read its script from a file so when you say "invalid result" I assume you're getting an error message like `can't open source file ' '`.

I THINK You probably were trying to use `-F` but then `' '` is the default FS value so there's no need to set it explicitly.

Once you've got past that issue, to get the output you want from that input file is just:

```
$ awk '{print $(NF-3), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
D20140624 username userid
D20140625 username1 userid1
D20140626 username2 userid2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner, using indexes from the end of the fields:

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[-4,-2,-1]"' file
```

Or with more explicit logic:

```
perl -lane 'print @F == 5 ? "@F[1,3,4]" : "@F[0,2,3]"' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.